# Can I tell which thread called my service method?

Tags: android, multithreading

Let's say I have a service that spawns 2 threads.
These 2 threads can access any of the service's methods.
Is there any way I can tell (within a method) which of the threads had called it?

I know such a mechanism exists for processes in Android: I can use getCallingUid for instance, but is there something similar for threads as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread.currentThread()  will always deliver current thread.

Comment: it is not.  getId()  is instance method, while currentThread() is static  - it delivers you thread you are calling it from. Then you can use getId() on it

Answer (score 3):

You can use `currentThread` method to get thread and use `getName` to get it's name:

```
String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
Log.d("Service", "Called from " + name + " thread");
```

When you create create thread you can specify it's name in constructor. See [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)

Comment: In my case the threads don't have names (I could do this, but I am actually doing this inside the Android frameworks so I prefer not to make too many changes...)

Comment: @androidcompile what do you exactly want? You can get current thread name and id from `Thread.currentThread()`. What do you want to accomplish using id or name?

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass in the [Thread.getId](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#getId%28%29) ?

Comment: I guess you mean putting this inside the service's method. I'll try that... wouldn't it just return the service's own thread id?

Comment: Just get the thread id in the thread code before calling the service, and pass it as a parameter to the service.